# thrust copy_if: incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I'm trying to use ***thrust::copy_if*** to compact an array with a predicate checking for positive numbers:

header file: file.h:

```
struct is_positive
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(const int x)
  {
    return (x >= 0);
  }
};
```

and file.cu

```
#include "../headers/file.h"
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>


void compact(int* d_inputArray, int* d_outputArray, const int size)
{
  thrust::device_ptr<int> t_inputArray(d_inputArray);
  thrust::device_ptr<int> t_outputArray(d_outputArray);
  thrust::copy_if(t_inputArray, t_inputArray + size, d_outputArray, is_positive());
}
```

I'm getting error messages starting with:

> /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/system/detail/generic/memory.inl(40):
>   error: incomplete type is not allowed

[full errormsg here](http://pastebin.com/9VX9tPPH)

If I just use ***copy*** instead of ***copy_if***, the code compiles fine, so I ruled everything except the predicate ***is_positive()*** out.

Thank you in advance for any help or general tips on how to debug such thrust errors.

**e:** I'm using Cuda 7.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it looks like you just have a typo.  This:

```
thrust::copy_if(t_inputArray, t_inputArray + size, d_outputArray, is_positive());
                                                   ^
```

should be this:

```
thrust::copy_if(t_inputArray, t_inputArray + size, t_outputArray, is_positive());
```

You've mixed a raw pointer with proper thrust device pointers, and this is causing trouble.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. Thank you, you're right, works like a charm!